# AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered

Tags: ios, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I am using AVQueuePlayer but it is crashing some times. I am getting this log

```
AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
```

what is the region for crashing please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added an observer for any key, you have to remove observer. You can do so by adding on the s deinit method

```
deinit {
   <observee>.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath::"<your key>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to remove observer for your player.

Do you have some code like this? `player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval`

If so, you need to add this line in `deinit` method of your controller / object:

```
player.removeTimeObserver(observer)
```

Also you maybe forget about this one:

```
player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate")
```